# Custom written iOS native module not exported

Tags: ios, react-native

As my title says, I created a bare bones iOS native module in react native and it is not appearing in the final `NativeModules` javascript object. Here's exactly what I'm doing. I'm pretty stumped by this.

1. Create fresh project with `react-native init testproj`
2. Open ios folder of `testproj` in xcode and create a `Cocoa Touch Class` called `MyModule`
3. In `MyModule.h` I have the following:

   ```
   #import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

   @interface MyModule : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>
   @end
   ```
4. In `MyModule.m` I have the following:

   ```
   #import "MyModule.h"

   @implementation MyModule
     RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()
   @end
   ```
5. I run `react-native run-ios` and the app builds successfully. When printing out the `NativeModules` like so:

   ```
   import React, {Component} from 'react';
   import {NativeModules} from 'react-native'

   export default class App extends Component {

     componentWillMount() {
       console.log('my modules! ', NativeModules)
     }

     render() {
       ...
     }
   }
   ```

   I don't see `MyModule` in the console logs but I see all of the base react native modules.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this would happen? Is there something I'm missing in the xcode build phase? For more context, these are the relevant versions:

- `xcode` `9.4.1`
- `react` `16.4.0`
- `react-native` `0.55.4`
- Running on `iPhone 6 - 11.4` simulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Native will not expose your native module if it doesn't have any methods.
You need to export at least one method using the `RCT_EXPORT_METHOD` (or `RCT_REMAP_METHOD`) macro before you will be able to access it.

Comment: Yep this is exactly it. I was misled by react native's documentation. Thank you!